# 2013 LED TV FH60xx Series (UN55FH6030FXZA) TV from Samsung Not Turning On

Tags: power-supply, hdmi, tv

So I have a 2013 LED TV FH60xx Series (UN55FH6030FXZA) TV from Samsung that does not want to power on and my computer does not detect it as a source. The fuse is still good and the LED lamps for the backlight are still good. When I first plug it in the backlight turns on quickly then off and the proper voltages seem to be present. Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Comment: If it doesn't work as a TV, why would you expect it to work with your PC?

Comment: It's where its been used and now it decided not to work. I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: No, you omitted information. Have you tested it as a TV without PC???

Comment: Because Spectrum has switched over fully to digital you can only use the HDMI inputs making it required for you to have a box, either way you would have to use HDMI so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing and and reverse engineering I have determined that the main board has a fault. The power supply and t-board both seem to be in working condition.